# How to use Semantic UI modules in React?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui

I can't seem to make semantic ui work inside React component. JQuery is working properly. But semantic accordion doesn't respond to click event.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import 'semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css'

import $ from 'jquery'
import jQuery  from 'jquery'
window.jQuery = jQuery
import 'semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.js'

export default class App extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
          <div className="ui slider checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" />
            <label>Accept terms and conditions</label>
          </div>
          <div className="ui styled accordion">
  <div className="active title">
    <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
    What is a dog?
  </div>
  <div className="active content">
    <p>A dog is a type of domesticated animal. Known for its loyalty and faithfulness, it can be found as a welcome guest in many households across the world.</p>
  </div>
  <div className="title">
    <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
    What kinds of dogs are there?
  </div>
  <div className="content">
    <p>There are many breeds of dogs. Each breed varies in size and temperament. Owners often select a breed of dog that they find to be compatible with their own lifestyle and desires from a companion.</p>
  </div>
  <div className="title">
    <i className="dropdown icon"></i>
    How do you acquire a dog?
  </div>
  <div className="content">
    <p>Three common ways for a prospective owner to acquire a dog is from pet shops, private owners, or shelters.</p>
    <p>A pet shop may be the most convenient way to buy a dog. Buying a dog from a private owner allows you to assess the pedigree and upbringing of your dog before choosing to take it home. Lastly, finding your dog from a shelter, helps give a good home to a dog who may not find one so readily.</p>
  </div>
</div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Is semantic-ui a node module?  Or a file? If it is a file you need to make you `import` look like: `import './path/to/file/filename';`

Comment: @DavinTryon It's a node module.. The CSS and JS files load perfectly, but for unknown reason js file cannot find JQuery. It says "uncaught reference: jquery"

Answer (score 6):

Author of Semantic-UI-React here. Don't use jQuery in any React app. React maintains a virtual representation of the DOM that must be kept in perfect sync with the real DOM. In a React app, only React should manipulate the DOM. JQuery is a DOM manipulation Library. Using jQuery in a React app will break React.

This is why I wrote Semantic-UI-React:
http://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction#jquery-free

https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React

Answer (score 4):

One way to include semantic-ui correctly in your project is

1º Install semantic-ui from npm

```
npm install semantic-ui-css --save
```

2º Import it after jquery. You have to use `require`, `import` would throw "uncaught reference: jquery"

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
require('semantic-ui-css/semantic')
```

3º In your example, initialize the accordion after the component has been mounted

```
componentDidMount(){
    $('.ui.accordion') // You can use a ref here
      .accordion()
    ;
}
```

[Your example working](https://esnextb.in/?gist=f2822b0fa0be99c759592368026bc409)

Comment: See this comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/41913908/8997882. The author of Semantic-UI-React says not to use jQuery with it.

Comment: @MBak when this answer was written, Semantic-UI-React didn't exist & it was not possible to use semantic ui without jQuery.

Comment: Interesting. I'm pretty new to React so I did not know that.

Comment: I'm actually still struggling to get my Semantic UI React dropdown to work. Looks like only the 'simple' (non JS) version works. Do you know how to resolve this? I feel like I need to initialize it, but then the above answer says not to use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a React Boiler Plate with Semantic Ui React.  I put some intructions in README.md. Hope this will help  https://github.com/kennethmervin01/react-with-semantic